# Api in .Net Core System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I just started learning aboout Api'sand started building a simple one.
I built this EmployeeController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ApiHandsOn1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Employee")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        List<Employee> _employeeList = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    Name= "abc def",
                    Salary=20000,
                    Permanent= true,
                    //Department= { Id = 1, Name = "Payroll"},
                    Skills ={new Skill{ Id= 1 , Value= "HTML"},new Skill{ Id= 2 , Value="CSS"},new Skill{ Id= 1 , Value= "JS"} },
                    DateOfBirth = new DateTime(01/03/2002)
                },
                new Employee()
                {
                    Id=2,
                    Name= "ghi jkl",
                    Salary=25000,
                    Permanent= false,
                    //Department= { Id = 2, Name = "HR"},
                    Skills ={new Skill{ Id= 1 , Value= "HTML"},new Skill{ Id= 2 , Value="CSS"},new Skill{ Id= 1 , Value= "JS"} },
                    DateOfBirth = new DateTime(15/08/2005)
                }
            };

        public EmployeeController()
        {
            
        }

        private List<Employee> GetStandardEmployeeList()
        {
            
            return _employeeList;
        }
        // GET: EmployeeController
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetEmployees")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public List<Employee> GetStandard()
        {
            List<Employee> empList=GetStandardEmployeeList();
            return empList;
        }

       
    }
}
```

I have built models for respective classes.
But when I hit execute on Swagger , it throws an exception(at _employeeList):

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

What am I missing?

Comment: where is the exception thrown?

Comment: where I initialise the list _employeeList.

Comment: try initializing the list at constructor

Comment: @AmirHosseinParsapour I tried that also but it was still giving the same error.

Comment: What is Skills Type in your Employee class?

Comment: public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

Comment: You should probably do it like that: Skills = new List<Skills>(){new Skill{}, new Skill{}}

Comment: You don’t initialise `DateTime` like that; you will be getting a very unexpected value.

Comment: Like @sellotape mentioned, you will get really weird dates when initialising the `DateTime` in that manner. Actually it seems that you [are using ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_). You probably want `new DateTime(2002,3,1)` and `new DateTime(2005,8,15)`

Comment: @AmirHosseinParsapour Thanks a lot. You are right. It worked..
You could put that in the answer..

Comment: @smoksnes yeah I corrected it.Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `Skills` property like this:

```
Skills = new List<Skill>(){new Skill{}, new Skill{}}
```

and as @smoksnes mentioned, you should put your value between literals in `DateTime` Initialization